# Unable to add 4th Fragment to my Tabbed bar in my Tabbed Activity Project

Tags: android, android-fragments

i try to add a new fragment to my Tabbed Bar and did the following like i did for the Fragments before:
1. I created a Fragment and the layout for that
2. I added the Fragment name in my MainActivity:

```
 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                locations_fragment loc = new locations_fragment();
                return loc;
            case 1:
                qr_code qra = new qr_code();
                return qra;
            case 2:
                HTW_Fragment htw = new HTW_Fragment();
                return htw;
            case 3:
                Events_Fragment pre = new Events_Fragment();
                return pre;
            default:
                return null;


        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Locations";
            case 1:
                return "QR Code Scanner";
            case 2:
                return "HTW";
            case 3:
                return "Events";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

if i try to start my App it shows only the first three Fragment in my Tab Bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is actually simple. You said to adapter there is only 3 pages. 
 :)

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}
```

Replace it with `return 4;` and enjoy your 4-th page displayed.